# is Scripts/Home a reserved name for bundle?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

If i do

//BundleConfig.cs

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/Home").Include("~/Scripts/Home/Home.js"));
```

//index.cstml

```
@section scripts
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Home")
}
```

then the script is not going to get rendered in release mode, it works fine in debug mode without

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

but if i do

//BundleConfig.cs

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Home").Include("~/Scripts/Home/Home.js"));
```

//index.cstml

```
@section scripts
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Home")
}
```

then it works fine in both debug and release mode.

Is `Scripts/Home` a reserved name or something?

Note: I do not have anything else named `~/Scripts/Home` in `BundleConfig.cs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not `Scripts/Home` in particular but it must be a valid bundle name, or path to an actual file.

For example if you were to add the following to your View **without** adding the appropriate bundle name it would actually render the script directly from disk to the browser. (yay)

`@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js")`

But any reference to a non existent file or bundle name would cause an error, like these:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jquery/*.*") -- error, no wildcards either
@Scripts.Render("~/non-existant-directory-or-bundle-name") -- error
@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/no-such-file.js") -- error
```

Answer (score 1):

No, however the bundle name (~/Scripts/Home) cannot match either an existing folder or file.
For this reason, I leave my scripts in ~/Scripts/... but name the bundles ~/js/....